# Large .A2L file, quoted translation issue

Tags: notepad++

I'm looking for a little guidance from the seasoned users. I'm very new and I hope my wording comes out clear and legible.

I have a large .A2L file at 11.3 MB. It contains around 600,000 lines of data, code and quoted text. The quoted text is in German and I'd like to convert this into English.

By looking at the example below, you can see what I'm talking about.

/begin CHARACTERISTIC

```
FrmMng_tiACCAPoll_C
"Erlaubte Zeit zur CAN Polling der ACCA-Botschaft, wenn GRA"
VALUE
0x1D45BA
Kw_Wu16
655350.0
Time_ms
0.00
655350.0

FORMAT "%8.1"
EXTENDED_LIMITS 0.00 655350.0

/begin IF_DATA ASAP1B_CCP
    DP_BLOB
      0x00
      0x1D45BA
      0x2
/end IF_DATA
/begin IF_DATA ETK 
    DP_BLOB 
      0x1D45BA 
      0x2 
/end IF_DATA 
/begin IF_DATA ASAP1B_KWP2000 
    DP_BLOB 
      0x1D45BA 
      0x2 
/end IF_DATA 
/begin IF_DATA ASAP1B_MCMESS 
    DP_BLOB 
      0x1D45BA 
      0x2 
/end IF_DATA
```

This pattern is repeatable throughout the file. Many lines of code, then some German words in quotations.

Here's where I'm at as of right now.
Using some Regex code, I managed to get all the text from the original file. I also added line numbers so that I could reinsert the translated text back to where it originated from.

An example below.
        1. Line 4512:     "Kennlinie zur Negative Grenze für Beschleuningungssollwer"
    2. Line 4566:     "Kennlinie zur Positive Grenze für Beschleuningungssollwert"
    3. Line 4620:     "Offset auf Negative Beschleuningungsbegrenzung"

As you can see, I'm hoping to translate the text, in quotations, into English. Then, I can hopefully reinsert the translated text back into the correct line. In this case, line 4512 will be "Characteristic curve for the negative limit for acceleration setpoints."

I now have a nice, tidy, 16,000+ file that needs to be translated. When I send this 1 MB text file into Google translate, it does nothing with it. Not one change. I believe it has something to do with the numbers in the file.

I took this one step further and removed all the numbers and the word "line" from the file. This seemed to work. I almost have a fully translated list. The issue is, Google seems to have lost some sentences as my new file has less lines then my original file. Another issue is that without having the line numbers anymore, I don't know where to insert the newly translated messages.

I'm new and I'm trying to learn but I'll admit, this is out of my league. Can anyone offer some guidance or suggestions?

I thank you for your time and have a great day.

Shayne

Answer (score 0):

Try with this procedure:

1. Open the file
2. Place the cursor at the beginning of the first line
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
4. Mark "Text to insert" and write: "Linie : " (without the quotes), then <kbd>OK</kbd>
5. Place the cursor on the first line, just before ":"
6. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
7. Mark "Insert number": Select starting = 1; Increment by = 1, and padding zeroes (optional)
8. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. Search: `^Linie[^:]+:[ ](?!")[^\n]*(?:\r?\n|\z)`, replace by: `(nothing)`
9. Copy paste to google translator and translate.

I think one of the key things here was to use the word 'Linie' instead of 'Line'. Since you later want to translate all to English, probably mixing different languages makes the translator not working OK and perhaps skipping some lines.

Comment: Thank you Julio for your tip. I ended up with a with fully translated word list. Now I need to figure out how to get the translated sentences back into their original position (line number) in my original file. The learning and reading continues.

Comment: Glad to hear! You can accept the answer if it worked for you. @Lunatic